# How to change time zone in calendar without changing my time format in java?

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

I have a problem in java. I have a calendar in my java program and I want to set time zone to my local time zone.

I was able do do this and it works very well. My problem is when I change time zone in calendar time format in calendar change to 12H from 24H and i don't want this!

my question is **How to change time zone in calendar without changing my time format in java?**

this is my code for time zone change :

```
public static Calendar setTimeZoneToTehran(Calendar calendar) {
        TimeZone timeZoneOfTehran = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tehran");
        calendar.setTimeZone(timeZoneOfTehran);
        return calendar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick thought, in case you are using time format to read/parse purpose you can use SimpleDateFormat to the desired format.

```
Date date = calendar.getTime();
System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

Comment: DataFormat return a string.I want do this in calendar.

Comment: Knowing what you want to do with this calendar would help as Calendar class is not meant for formatting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As @devilpreet already said, formatting in Calendar is only additional, bonus feature. This class is designed to keep info about date and time, formatting of date is encapuslated in `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Moreover, consider using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or java.time(from Java 8) instead of `java.util.Calendar`(in some circles using java.util.Calendar and Date is considered a bad practice).